# How to create a key when producing a dimension and fact table from single table when the prod can't be unique identified?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powerbi

I have a wide table called Sales.

Each row represents a sale. It has got various info like sales, customer, product.

I'm building a star schema from this using SQL to create product dimension using:

```
Select distinct prodnumber,prodname,size,class
From sales
```

Building fact table as follows:

```
Select salesamt,salesdate,prodnumber,prodname,size,class
From sales
```

The reason for having prod fields in fact table is that-
A unique product unfortunately isn't identified by productnumber, rather by prodnumber,prodname,size,class.

Hence the key is a combination.

So in Power BI when joining the prod dimension and fact table in the final report I need to join on 4 columns. Is there an alternative way to do this? Like somehow generating a unique key to make the join simpler?

Comment: Try making a view of the prod perhaps (I assume Product) here - see where names enhance clarity :) with those columns and the primary key

Answer (score 2):

**This answer is done in Power BI PowerQuery**.
It is doing the almost exactly the same thing as the other SQL answer.

For your first query, let's call it `Dim Product`, Go to `Add Column` in the ribbon, and select `Index Column` > `From 1`. Then in the formula bar, rename `"Index"` to `"ID"` (or similar).

For your second query, let's call it `Fact Sale`, in the `Home` tab in the ribbon, select `Merge Queries`. In the pop-up:

- Select 'Dim Product` in the drop-down in the middle.
- Under `Fact Sale` at the top click on `prodnumber` column, then while holding down `Ctrl` or `Shift`, select `prodname`, `size`, and `class`. You should see 1, 2, 3, 4 appear in their headers.
- Do the same for `Dim Product` headers, ensuring the same order as above.

It should look like:
[image]

Finally:

- Select columns `prodnumber`, `prodname`, `size`, `class` - and remove those columns.
- Click on the double arrows in the `Dim Product` header, and only select `ID`, and uncheck `Use original column name as prefix`.
- Rename the new `ID` column to `Product ID` if you like.

And that's it.

Comment: Perhaps put actual SQL in your answer or full power bi code with the solution since this is about that

Comment: Perhaps it is also about Power BI and merely presenting an alternative solution.

Comment: Yes, perhaps; as you note a couple of ways to solve this particular one here; we will let the OP decide as other options appear; this is not "horrid" to me, just pointing out to perhaps add the full code (I don't  consider myself a PowerBI expert though either) My reference was to the " Is there an alternative way to do this? " from the question so perhaps this is sufficient.

Comment: Think this is a perfectly valid in power BI solution, OP could use either my SQL solution or this depending on if they want to create a database schema that handles it 
Would need to set up a procedure and job to fill the tables but would save the hassle and allow for more flexibility in future should further changes be required. As a quick and easy solution though this does the job better.

Comment: Thanks all I liked both solutions I will test this

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.PRODUCT_DIM
(
PRODUCT_PK INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
PRODNUMBER INT NOT NULL,
PRODNAME NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
SIZE NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
CLASS NVARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO DBO.PRODUCT_DIM
(
PRODNUMBER,
PRODNAME,
SIZE,
CLASS
)
SELECT DISTINCT
PRODNUMBER,
PRODNAME,
SIZE,
CLASS
FROM SALES
```

Then you will need to include the PK (in an FK form) in your fact table
You can find what this is by doing the select as follows

CREATE THE FACT TABLE FIRST WITH THE COLUMNS LISTED APART FROM THE PRODNUMBER, PRODNAME, CLASS AND SIZE COLUMNS BUT WITH A PRODUCT_FK INT NOT NULL

```
INSERT INTO SALES_FACT
(
SALESAMT,
SALESDATE
PRODUCT_FK
)

Select S.salesamt,S.salesdate, P.PRODUCT_PK
From sales S
INNER JOIN PRODUCT_DIM P
ON 
P.PRODNUMBER = S.PRODNUMBER
P.PRODNAME = S.PRODNAME
P.SIZE = S.SIZE
P.CLASS = S.CLASS
```

Finally you can then join a single table using the product_pk and product_fk in your dim and fact tables respectively (if in power bi create the relationship on this)

Comment: I have just got read only permission so I can't do this (create/insert), maybe can do this using cte and row_number. I'm thinking whether this is a deterministic solution. Maybe I need to use order by on all columns when doing the rownumber.